# Scraping data using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I structure like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Tel. nr.:</strong>
        +370 000 000
        <strong>Faksas:</strong>
        +370 5 0000
    </td>
</tr>
```

I new in using Simple HTML DOM. What I need, I need content **+370 000 000** and **+370 5 0000** . I see that this library does not support Xpath, how can I write a query where I can extract the contents after the HTML link `<strong>Tel. nr.:</strong>` ?

I found only one way, get HTML and with regex get text from `</strong>` till `<strong>`, but maybe Simple HTML DOM have own method for this?

Comment: where are your codes? try to use children inside the `<td>`

Comment: I think the RegEx method you provided is legit. I just went through the documentation, and you can simplify your work by examining all data from `</strong>` to `<` instead of `</strong>` to  `<strong>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
   <?php
    require('simple_parser.php');
    $html = str_get_html('
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>Tel. nr.:</strong>
            +370 000 000
            <strong>Faksas:</strong>
            +370 5 0000
        </td>
    </tr>');
    $td =$html->find('td',0) ; 
    echo $td->plaintext;

    ?>
```

Post your full code to get a clear answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use `->find('text')` in order to get the text nodes:

```
$sample_html = '
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Tel. nr.:</strong>
        +370 000 000
        <strong>Faksas:</strong>
        +370 5 0000
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
';

$html = str_get_html($sample_html);
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $first_td = $row->find('td', 0);
    echo $first_td->find('text', 2);
    echo $first_td->find('text', 4);
}
```

But this solution is rather clunky. One removal of those newlines on the elements would yield another result.

I suggest use `DOMDocument` with xpath instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($sample_html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//tr[1]/td[1]/text()');
foreach($elements as $e) {
    echo trim($e->textContent) . '<br/>';
}
```